# I am having a problem with mongodb aggregate function for nested lookups

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate-functions

I can't add username of the volunteer along with the volunteer's data

**User**

```
_id:,
user_id:,
username:
```

**Volunteer**

```
_id:,
user_id:,(the user who volunteered)
post_id:,(the post on which he volunteered)
```

**Post**

```
_id:,
user_id:,(the person who posted)
Title:,
Description:,
```

**Output of POST I want**

```
_id:,
user_id:,(the user who posted)
Title:,
Description:,
PostVolunteers:[
{
_id:,
user_id:,(the user who volunteered)
post_id:,
username:,(username of the person who volunteered)
},
{
_id:,
user_id:,(the user who volunteered)
post_id:,
username:,(username of the person who volunteered)
}
]
```

**Current Code**

```
post = await Post.aggregate([


      {
        $lookup: {
          from: Volunteer.collection.name,
          localField: "_id", 
          foreignField: "post_id", 
          as: "PostVolunteers",
        },
      },
```

Along with volunteer details such as post_id and user_id, i want username of the volunteering person. I cant seem to do it.

Comment: Since that data is not in the volunteer collection, have you tried another lookup to the user collection?

Comment: I did try another lookup. Then it was only displaying the username not the volunteer's data which was previously being displayed. But i want both.